# how to mount nfs on OSX so I can create new files?

Tags: macos, nfs

I mounted `restoredb` directory to my OS X 10.6.2 via Disk Utility with Advanced Mount Parameters = `resvport`.

I am able to **edit** files that are in the mounted directory but I am **not able to create** new files.

Any idea how to fix that? I can create files if I look as root

**/etc/exports** on nfs server (testing)

```
/srv/www/htdocs/restoredb       10.0.0.210(rw,no_root_squash)
```

mount on OSX gives me this output

```
 map -static on /Users/radek/Sites/restoredb (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
 testing:/srv/www/htdocs/restoredb on /Users/radek/Sites/restoredb (nfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give yourself *write* permissions on the `/srv/www/htdocs/restoredb` directory in order to create or delete files.

Comment: before mount `drwxrwxrwx   2 radek  procview        68 30 Mar 09:34 restoredb`

Comment: after mount `dr-xr-xr-x   2 root   staff            1 30 Mar 17:20 restoredb`

Comment: ownwership and permissions above before I posted my question

Comment: files inside after mount `-rw-r--r--  1 radek  procview  18249 30 Mar 17:14 index.php`

Comment: @Radek You need to change permissions *on the server*.

Comment: @Daniel: it works but what if I cannot change permissions/owner on the server?

Comment: @Radek The server admin sets up the permissions. AFAIK, NFS uses the Unix user IDs for that, so you need to figure out what user IDs have permissions, and change your local user accounts' user IDs accordingly. It's probably best to keep the users of both systems in sync somehow. Change OS X user account IDs in *System Preferences » Accounts » Right-click an account » Advanced…* (which is rather dangerous if you don't know what you're doing, I am told)

Comment: my point is what if I need the user to be let's say php with permissions 750 on the server but locally I want user radek to edit/create?

Comment: @Radek: You will have to `chgrp` the directory to yourself and apply `g+rwx` permissions. *On the server.* If the server doesn't let you, you can't do it client-side.

Comment: In the previous comment, I was going to suggest adding yourself to the directory's ACL, but I'm not sure if it will work over NFSv3. (AFAIK, older NFS versions (pre-v4) do all checking client-side using only the permission bits. But I may be wrong.)

Comment: ok, thank you. I am happy how it works now :-)